# Replace numeric genotype code with DNA letter in VCF file

Tags: r, dplyr

Here I have a modified VCF file, where the genotype of each sequenced line is represented numerically, and the corresponding SNP letters are in a list the SNP column (I generated this column by aggregating together the Ref and Alt columns).

**Using dplyr**, I would like to replace the numeric value with the SNP letter. All positions are homozygous, and the SNP list is in the order of the numeric genotype, so using the first number of the numeric genotype (plus 1) should give the list index of the corresponding SNP letter. Like this:

```
                  Ref   1st Alt   2nd Alt   3rd Alt
SNP letter:       C     A         T         G
Numeric genotype: 0     1         2         3
List index:       1     2         3         4
```

Modified VCF dataframe:

```
CHR   POS   SNP              Line1   Line2   Line3
01    10    c("A", "G")      0|0     1|1     0|0
01    20    c("C", "T", "A") 2|2     0|0     1|1
02    15    c("G", "T")      1|1     0|0     1|1
```

Desired output:

```
CHR   POS   SNP              Line1   Line2   Line3
01    10    c("A", "G")      A       G       A
01    20    c("C", "T", "A") A       C       T
02    15    c("G", "T")      T       G       T
```

So far I've tried something like this:

```
VCF %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(4:ncol(.)), funs(str_replace(., "^(\\d)|\\d", SNP[[1]]["\\1"+1])))
```

but have not been successful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Structure is:

```
VCF <- structure(list(CHR = c("01", "01", "01"), POS = c(29463, 
29517, 29522), SNP = list(c("T", "C"), c("C", "G", "A"), c("T", 
"C")), PI548298 = c("0|0", "0|0", "1|1"), PI548488 = c("0|0", "0|0", 
"0|0"), PI548348 = c("0|0", "0|0", "1|1")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: 1) Can you post your data using `dput` so we can work with the data you actually have? For example, is SNP  really  a string containing  an R expression, not an actual vector or list? 2) In the 3 line columns, are there ever heterozygous SNPs? Can we just ignore the second number in each "Line" column? If not, how do you want to deal with that?

Comment: Edited to include dput. Yes, all positions will be homozygous, so the second number can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by using `substr` to get the first character of each `PI`  column (since that's all the information we need from it), converting it to numeric, adding 1 (since R indices start at 1), and then using that to subset the `SNP` column.

By using `rowwise`, we apply this function on each row individually and make use of that row's SNP vector:

```
library(tidyverse)

VCF %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('PI')),
              list(~ SNP[as.numeric(substr(., 0, 1)) + 1]))

Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  CHR     POS SNP       PI548298 PI548488 PI548348
  <chr> <dbl> <list>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 01    29463 <chr [2]> T        T        T       
2 01    29517 <chr [3]> C        C        C       
3 01    29522 <chr [2]> C        T        C
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you @divibisan.